# Rails 3.1 and Coffeescript: Require entire directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets, asset-pipeline

There is a require for individual files like so:

```
//= require controllers/documents
```

Is there an equivalent for requiring a directory?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yep:

```
//= require_tree controllers
```

By the way, you tagged this as `coffeescript`, but your question uses JavaScript comment syntax... so for the record, in CoffeeScript you want to use `#=`, not `//=`.

Also, this is actually a [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) question, not a Rails question. Sprockets is a default in Rails 3.1, but you can use it independently as well. At any rate, the Sprockets page offers documentation aplenty on `require`, `require_tree`, and many other handy directives.

Comment: Using this may give a *require_tree argument must be a directory* error (in my case, using CoffeeScript with Rails 4). Solution is to actually use a path, like `#= require_tree ./controllers`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8550646/472768